# With DI, create a new instance every time the interface is used

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have something like the code below.

The inyected class has a state, so I want to create a clean **new instance** of the class implementing INumberWriter every time it is called. Is there a way to do this?

```
public class NumberWriter() : INumberWriter{
   private int i = 1;
   public void Write(){
      ConsoleWrite(i++);
   }
}

public class SomeClass(){
   private INumberWriter writer;
   public SomeClass(INumberWriter writer){
      this.writer= writer;
   }

   public void AMethod(){
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
         writer.Write();// I want to see on console 11111 insted of 12345
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Currently an `INumberWriter` implementation is injected each time an instance of `SomeClass` is created. So calling a method on that `INumberWriter` instance does not involve dependency injection anymore - it has already been resolved.
If you want DI to solve this problem you'll have to obtain a new `INumberWriter` instance inside the for-loop of the `AMethod()` method.

Comment: How about injecting a NumberWriterFactory and manufacturing a new NumberWriter each pass of the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I was hoping a special configuration or something to help in this case. I think @CaiusJard approach is the best option I have right now

Comment: I did also wonder about whether you could/would just provide a Reset() method on the instance you have, and Reset it every pass. It's sometimes hard to know which way to jump with small/contrived examples

Comment: I'd really like to know the underlying problem that is trying to be solved here. Your attempted solution is just so very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that your DI Container can (or arguably should) solve for you. It's the DI Container's job to inject a dependency into a consumer. After that, the consumer stores the dependency in a private field, which means that -as long as the consumer lives- it will reuse that same dependency.

Fortunately, you are programming to interfaces, which means you can solve this problem using a special [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) implementation that can be placed inside your application's [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). For instance:

```cs
public class AlwaysNewNumberWriter : INumberWriter
{
    public void Write() => new NumberWriter().Write();
}
```

Instead of registering `NumberWriter` in the container, you can now register `AlwaysNewNumberWriter` as follows:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<INumberWriter, AlwaysNewNumberWriter>();
```

This solution, however, might be too simplistic, because `NumberWriter` might have dependencies of its own, that need to be resolved from the DI Container. In that case, you'll need a slightly more complex solution:

```cs
public class DispatchingNumberWriter : INumberWriter
    where TNumberWriter : INumberWriter
{
    private readonly Func<INumberWriter> factory;
    
    public DispatchingNumberWriter(Func<INumberWriter> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void Write() => this.factory.Invoke().Write();
}
```

This `DispatchingNumberWriter` accepts a `Func<INumberWriter>` factory delegate, which it calls every time its `Write` method is called. This allows you to, instead of injecting the `NumberWriter` implementation into consumers, inject this `DispatchingNumberWriter`.

The following code demonstrates how to wire everything together:

```cs
services.AddTransient<NumberWriter>();

services.AddScoped<INumberWriter>(c =>
    new DispatchingNumberWriter(
        () => c.GetRequiredService<NumberWriter>()));
```

Please note the following about this last snippet:

- The `DispatchingNumberWriter` is supplied with a delegate that calls back into the DI Container to resolve a new `NumberWriter`. This allows the `NumberWriter` to be created by the DI Container, which might construct the type using Auto-Wiring, i.e. automatically detecting and injecting its dependencies.
- Because `NumberWriter` is created by the DI Container, it is registered as `Transient`; otherwise instances might still be reused.
- The `DispatchingNumberWriter` is registered as Scoped, which the safest lifestyle for this class, because:

  - Registering `DispatchingNumberWriter` as `Singleton` will cause it's `c` parameter and the call to its `GetRequiredService` method to run in the container's global scope. This can cause issues in case `NumberWriter` or one of its transient dependencies start implementing `IDisposable` (which could result in a memory leak) or in case `NumberWriter` has direct or indirect dependencies with the `Scoped` lifestyle (which would make those dependencies `Singletons`).
  - Registering `DispatchingNumberWriter` as `Transient` will have the desired effect except in case it gets (accidentally) directly or indirectly injected into `Singleton` consumer. Because in that case you'll get the same behavior as described in the previous point with `DispatchingNumberWriter` registered as `Singleton`. Although the problem isn't different when injecting a `Scoped` `DispatchingNumberWriter` into a `Singleton` consumer, MS.DI prevents the injection of `Scoped` dependencies into `Singleton` consumers, because it is [known pitfall](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) to prevent.

Comment: Isn't your first implementation of the proxy essentially a factory as creation of the writer doesn't happen in the container but within the proxy? Anyway your `DispatchingNumberWriter`-class has a pointless `where`-constraint although the class isn't generic - maybe a relict of some intermediate solution?

Comment: This might be a semantic discussion, but an important property of a factory is that it *returns* the created object. In other words a factory abstraction exposes the created type as output parameter in its definition. This is not the case with the `AlwaysNewNumberWriter`, which effecticely makes it *not* a factory. It does create a new type though, but the fact that this happens is hidden from it consumers. That's why it's *not* a Factory; in this case it's a Proxy.

Comment: The fact that a Factory returns a created type is also its biggest weakness, because it increases the complexity to the consumer, because the consumer now has to deal with two different types. For a more elaborate discussion on the downsides of Factories, see [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/abstract-factories/).

Comment: I see your point, however your `DispatchingNumberWriter` literally expects a `factory`-function. Of course this is just a name, however this is where creation of the object happens - which from my point *does* make it a factory-function.

Comment: On the other side I agree that your approach splits *creating* the type from *using* it, so clients don't need to know anything about that factory-function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted your point. Yes, the `Func<INumberWriter>` certainly *is* a factory. It walks like a factory, talks like a factory, and is even named `factory`. Difference is that this factory (abstraction) is locally used with the `DispatchingNumberWriter` and, therefore, -ideally- solely within your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

Answer (score 2):

When you **need** a new service on every iteration, you surely need to **create** a new one on every iteration. So there's no point in providing the dependency once upon creation of your `SomeClass`-instance, but upon every call to `AMethod`.

You may create some kind of factory to you class and let the factory create a new instance on each iteration:

```
public class WriterFactory
{
    public INumberWriter CreateNewWriter() => new NumberWriter();
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private WriterFactory factory;
    public SomeClass(WriterFactory factory){
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void AMethod()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            var writer = this.factory().CreateNewWriter();
            writer.Write();
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of providing a writer to your class, you provide a **factory** to the class which itself creates the writers.